# Unexpected behaviour reusing a TMemoryStream in Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, tstream

I am trying to read two strings of varying length from a TMemoryStream, but both streams end up being the same length.  So if, for example, the first string is 'abcdefghijkl', and the second one is 'wxyz', the value I get for the second string is 'wxyzefghijkl' (the first four characters of my new string ('wxyz') followed by the remaining characters of the 1st string that have not been replaced by 'wxyz'

My code is:-

```pascal
var
  L : LongInt
  S : string;

...
  msRecInfo.Position := 0;
  msRecInfo.Read(L, SizeOf(L)); // read size of following string ...

  SubStream.Clear;
  SubStream.CopyFrom(msRecInfo, L); // copy next block of data to a second TMemoryStream

  if (L > 0) then S := StreamToString(SubStream);  //convert the stream into a string

  msRecInfo.Read(L, SizeOf(L)); // get size of following string ...
  SubStream.CopyFrom(msRecInfo, L);
  if (L > 0) then S := StreamToString(SubStream);
```

I have been battling with this for hours without success.  Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You missed to clear SubStream before the second call to CopyFrom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not calling `SubStream.Clear()` before the 2nd call to `SubStream.CopyFrom()`.  So, the 1st call to `StreamToString(SubStream)` leaves `SubStream.Position` at the end of the stream, then the subsequent `SubStream.CopyFrom()` adds more data to the stream, *preserving* the existing data. Then the subsequent `StreamToString(SubStream)` reads all of the data from `SubStream`.

Also, be aware that if `L` is `0` when you pass it to `SubStream.CopyFrom()`, it will copy the *entire* `msRecInfo` stream.  This is documented behavior:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStream.CopyFrom

> **If Count is 0, CopyFrom sets Source position to 0 before reading and then copies the entire contents of Source into the stream.** If Count is greater than or less than 0, CopyFrom reads from the current position in Source.

So, you need to move up your `L > 0` check, eg:

```
msRecInfo.Read(L, SizeOf(L));
if (L > 0) then
begin
  SubStream.Clear;
  SubStream.CopyFrom(msRecInfo, L);
  S := StreamToString(SubStream);
end
else
  S := '';
```

I would suggest wrapping this logic into a reusable function, eg:

```
var
  L : LongInt;
  S : string;

  function ReadString: string;
  begin
    msRecInfo.Read(L, SizeOf(L)); // read size of following string ...
    if (L > 0) then
    begin
      SubStream.Clear;
      SubStream.CopyFrom(msRecInfo, L); // copy next block of data to a second TMemoryStream
      Result := StreamToString(SubStream);  //convert the stream into a string
    end else
      Result := '';
  end;
begin
  ...
  msRecInfo.Position := 0;
  S := ReadString;
  S := ReadString;
  ...
```

Although, if feasible, I would suggest just getting rid of `SubStream` altogether, update `StreamToString()` to take `L` as an input parameter, so that you can read the `string` from `msRecInfo` directly, eg:

```
msRecInfo.Read(L, SizeOf(L));
S := StreamToString(msRecInfo, L);
```

No need for a 2nd `TMemoryStream` if you can avoid it.